# Docker compose mounts volume for one service only

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build two services that mount the same volumes. Running the following docker-compose configuration allows the `cms` service to mount the directory, however, the `client` service does not mount the directory.

I've tried docker inspect for the service, and `mounts` is just an empty array.

```
version: "2"
services:
  cms:
    container_name: cms_keystone
    build: ./cms_keystone/
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=docker_production
    ports:
      - "3010:3000"
    volumes:
      - /data/naqib.info_static_content:/data/naqib.info_static_content:rw

  client:
    container_name: client_nextjs
    build: ./client_nextjs/
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=docker_production
      # - YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/data/naqib.info_static_content/shm/yarn_cache
    ports:
      - "8001:7001"
      - "8002:7002"
    depends_on:
      - cms
    volumes:
      - /data/naqib.info_static_content:/data/naqib.info_static_content:ro
```

Any suggestion what should I do to debug?

Update:
I'm not sure if it is relevant here, but the volume in the host machine is an HDD connected via USB3.

Comment: Should the very last line end in either `ro` or `rw`, not just `r`?

Comment: ro. I copied it wrong.